# Как экспортировать переменные окружения в Node.js

Tags: node.js

Использую prerender и хочу сделать его доступным по логину и паролю. В документации сказано, что это делается следующими строками:

```
export BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=prerender
export BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=test
```

А как экспортировать эти переменные в Node.js? Знаю, что можно просто выполнить команду:

```
BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=prerender BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=test node prerender.js
```

Но я использую `pm2`, чтобы проект крутился в фоне, поэтому мне нужно экспортировать эти переменные непосредственно в коде. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то как-то так:

```
BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME = process.env.BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME
```

Если же вам нужно наоборот, то так:

```
process.env['BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'] = 'prerender'
```